# Selectively activate buttons

Tags: javascript, button

i wanted to make the button such that if button A is click, A will disable. And when B is click B will disabled and will reactive button A.

How can i change my code? to achieve this? This i would like to make this function can work with more buttons later on. If A is click, then A disabled and B,C,D will be activated.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation Test</title>


</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250" style="border:solid 1px #000000;">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
    <button id="start" type="button" start.disable = "true" onClick="loadingComplete(); SetButtonStatus()" />Start</button>
    <button id="pause" type="button" pause.disable="false" onClick=";SetButtonStatus();" />Pause</button>    
    <button id="reset" type="button" pause.disable="false" onClick=";SetButtonStatus();" />Reset</button>

    </div>
<script>
var surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var surfaceContext = surface.getContext('2d');
var happy;
var x = 50;
var y = 0;
var x1 = 150;
var y1 = 120;
var dirX = 3;
var dirY = 1;
var dirX1 = 2;
var dirY1 = 2;

var bgImage = new Image();
bgImage.src = "Pictures/PondEnvironment/pond.png";

bgImage.onload = function () {
    surfaceContext.drawImage(bgImage, 0, 0, 250, 250);
};



        function SetButtonStatus()
        {

            if (document.getElementById('start').disabled == false)
            {
                document.getElementById('start').disabled=true;
                document.getElementById('pause').disabled=false;
                document.getElementById('reset').disabled=false;    
                return 0;}

            if (document.getElementById('pause').disabled == false )
            {
                document.getElementById('pause').disabled =true;
                document.getElementById('start').disabled =false;
                return 0;
            }

            if (document.getElementById('reset').disabled == false )
            {
                document.getElementById('pause').disabled =false;
                document.getElementById('reset').disabled =false;
                document.getElementById('start').disabled =true;
                return 0;
            }

        } 




    /*function disable(buttonid){
        var button1_name;
        var button2_name;

        if(button1_name==1){
            document.getElementById('button1').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('button2').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('button1').name=0;
        }
        if(button2_name==3){
            document.getElementById('button2').disabled = true;
            document.getElementById('button1').disabled = false;
            document.getElementById('button2').name=0;
        }
    }
*/

function drawCanvas() {
    // Get our Canvas element
    //surface = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

    if (surface.getContext) {
        // If Canvas is supported, load the image
        happy = new Image();
        //happy.onload = loadingComplete;
        happy.src ="image/pic1.jpg";
        happy2 = new Image();
        happy2.src ="image/anchovies.png";
        var bgImage = new Image();
        bgImage.src = "Pictures/PondEnvironment/pond.png";
    }
}

function loadingComplete(e) {
    // When the image has loaded begin the loop
    setInterval(loop, 25);
    start.disable=true;
}

function loop() {
    // Each loop we move the image by altering its x/y position

    // Grab the context
    //var surfaceContext = surface.getContext('2d');

    // Clear the canvas to White
    //surfaceContext.fillStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    surfaceContext.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,250,250);
    //surfaceContext.fillRect(0, 0, surface.width, surface.height);

    // Draw the image
    surfaceContext.drawImage(happy, x, y, 50, 30);
    surfaceContext.drawImage(happy2, x1, y1, 50, 30);

    x += dirX;
    y += dirY;
    x1 += dirX1;
    y1 += dirY1;

    if (x <= 0 || x > 220 - 23) {
        dirX = -dirX;
    }
    if (y <= 0 || y > 250 - 30) {
        dirY = -dirY;
    }
    if (x1 <= 0 || x1 > 220 - 23) {
        dirX1 = -dirX1;
    }
    if (y1 <= 55 || y1 > 250 - 30) {
        dirY1 = -dirY1;
    }
}
</script>  
<script>drawCanvas(); </script> 
</body>
</html>
```

**EDITED**
I have changed the "disable" to "disabled" and I am trying to make the pause button to disable and enable back ?

```
   function startStatus()
    {

        if (start.disabled)
            start.disabled = "enabled";

       /* else if (pause.disabled = "true")
        {
            start.disabled ="disabled";
        }*/

        else if (start.disabled ="true")
        {
        //pause.disabled = "enabled"
        }


        if (pause.disabled)
        pause.disabled = "false";

        /* else if (pause.disabled = "true")
         {
         start.disabled ="disabled";
         }*/

        else if (start.disabled ="false")
        {
            //pause.disabled = "enabled"
        }

    }
```

Code updated::

I would like to make the following, but my code does not perform that.

1. click "Start_btn"

   - start btn -- disable
   - pause btn -- enable
   - reset btn -- enable
2. click "pause_btn"

   - start btn -- enable
   - pause btn -- disable
   - reset btn -- enable
3. click "reset_btn"

   - start btn -- enable
   - pause btn -- disable
   - reset btn -- disable

My code can be found here >>>> >http://jsfiddle.net/fN8XD/5/

Answer (score -2, accepted):

working your code

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/fN8XD/)

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Animation Test</title>
<script>
    function SetButtonStatus()
    {


       if (document.getElementById('start').disabled == false)
        {document.getElementById('start').disabled=true;
         document.getElementById('pause').disabled=false;        
        return 0;}

        if (document.getElementById('pause').disabled == false )
        {//i added this line**
        //pause.disabled ="enabled"
        document.getElementById('pause').disabled =true
        document.getElementById('start').disabled =false
            return 0;
        }//i added this line**

    /*else if(document.getElementById('pause').disabled == true )
    {document.getElementById('pause').disabled = false}*/

    }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="250" height="250" style="border:solid 1px #000000;">
            <p>Your browser doesn't support canvas.</p>
        </canvas>
        <button id="start" type="button"  onClick="SetButtonStatus()" />Start</button>

        <button id="pause" type="button" onClick="SetButtonStatus()"/>Pause</button>

    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sssonline2/fN8XD/)

Comment: -1 Please test your code before posting, and learn the difference between assignment and comparison.

Comment: Hi ... how can i reactive the Start btn when the pause btn is click and the pause been disabled ??

Comment: Its not working ...
   function startStatus()
    {
        var start = document.getElementById('start');
        
        if (start.disabled == true)
           //document.getElementById('start').disabled = true; 
            start.disabled = false;
        
        if(pause.disabled == true){
            start.disabled = "disabled";
            //pause.disabled = false;
        }
   

        else if (start.disabled ="false")
        {
            pause.disabled = false;
        }
        
    }

Comment: i will test my code and get back with js fiddle thnx every one

Answer (score 0):

In your code (my wrapping):

```
> <button id="start" type="button" start.disable = "false" 
>  onClick="loadingComplete(); SetButtonStatus()" />Start</button>
```

Your code relies on the id "start" being made a global variable referencing the element with id "start", that is a non–standard feature introduced by IE (and copied by other browsers for compatability) that is widely considered a very bad idea, do not use it.

There is no standard attribute for the button element of "start.disable", so many browsers will not provide access through a same named element property. A property name with a period can't be accessed using javascript dot notation, it must be accessed using bracket notation. Some browsers will make it available as `element['start.disable']`, but all browsers will make it available as `getAttribute('start.disable')`.

However, I think you are acually after the disabled attribute.

Finally, the closing part of the start tag has a misplaced "/" that is used in XML to signify an empty element. This clearly isn't XML, and if it was it would result in a syntax error from the rest of the element markup. What I think you want is:

```
<button id="start" type="button" disabled 
 onClick="loadingComplete(); SetButtonStatus()">Start</button>
```

Note also that the disabled attribute results in the realted DOM element having a disabled property set to `true` (that is, boolean true, not the string "true"). Therefore your code can be:

```
var start = document.getElementById('start');

if (start.disabled) {

  // toggle status
  start.disabled = false;

 } ...
```

and so on.

Note that you could write:

```
if (start.disabled == true)
```

but the above is less to type and equivalent.